# Foundry Test for a function with array of structs

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I have this foundry function and I don't have any idea how to pass an array of structs to batchList function

```
function test_ListMockERC721() public {
    vm.prank(add1);
    erc721Mock.mint(msg.sender);
    marketsc.batchList([[erc721Mock, 1, 0, add1, 1], [erc721Mock, 2, 0, add1, 1]]);
}
```

This is the function signature from the smart contract:

`function batchList(InputOrder[] calldata inputOrders) external;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that InputOrder is a structure. Then the solution is:

```
function test_ListMockERC721() public {
    vm.prank(add1);
    erc721Mock.mint(msg.sender);
    marketsc.InputOrder[] memory inputOtders = new marketsc.InputOrder[](2);
    inputOtders[0] = marketsc.InputOrder(erc721Mock, 1, 0, add1, 1);
    inputOtders[1] = marketsc.InputOrder(erc721Mock, 2, 0, add1, 1);
    marketsc.batchList(inputOtders);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since solidity does not natively support passing an array of structs in a function from the outside of the smart contract, you have to decompose the struct array into several basic type arrays and reassemble them in the function.
Here is a sample array of structs:

```
struct InputOrder {
address token;    
uint256 tokenId;
uint256 tokenAmount;
address payable recipient;  
uint8 v;    
bytes32 r;   
bytes32 s;   }
```

If you want to pass an array of InputOrder structs, we need to decompose them into 7 arrays: an address array for the token, a uint array for the tokenId, a uint array for the tokenAmount, an address array for the recipient, a uint8 array for v, a bytes32 array for r, and a bytes32 array for s.
Your smart contract batchList function could look something like this:

```
function batchList(
    address[] calldata token,
    uint256[] calldata tokenId,
    uint256[] calldata tokenAmount,
    address[] calldata recipient,
    uint8[] calldata v,
    bytes32[] calldata r,
    bytes32[] calldata s
) external {
    // Here you can iterate through one of the arrays (i.e., token array) and then
    // reconstruct your struct using the corresponding index for other arrays.
    for (uint i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
        InputOrder memory inputOrder = InputOrder({
            token: token[i],
            tokenId: tokenId[i],
            tokenAmount: tokenAmount[i],
            recipient: recipient[i],
            v: v[i],
            r: r[i],
            s: s[i]
        });
        // Do something with inputOrder
    }
}
```

In your test function, you can call the batchList function as follows:

```
function test_ListMockERC721() public {
    // other code here.
    marketsc.batchList(
        [erc721Mock, erc721Mock],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 0],
        [add1, add1],
        [1, 1],
        [bytes32 exampleR, bytes32 exampleR],
        [bytes32 exampleS, bytes32 exampleS]
    );
}
```